# Computing the gradient of the log-partition function in a linear-chain conditional random field (CRF) model

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, maximum-entropy, conditional-random-field

**Query.**

**When computing the gradient of the log-partition function for an exponential family distribution specified by the linear-chain conditional random field (CRF) model, will unary conditional distributions $p(y_t | \mathbf{x})$ need to be computed in addition to pairwise conditional distributions $p(y_t, y_{t-1} | \mathbf{x})$, depending on whether the feature function is a node/state feature or edge/transition feature?**

**Context.**

The need for computing the gradient of the negative conditional log-likelihood arises in stochastic gradient descent for estimation of linear-chain CRF parameters.

In order to compute the gradient of the conditional log-likelihood, the non-trivial term that needs to be computed is the gradient of the log-partition function. As the conditional probability $p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}; \Theta)$ with parameter $\Theta = (\theta_1, \dots, \theta_K)$ defined by a linear-chain CRF is in the exponential family, the gradient of the conditional log-partition function is the conditional expectation of the sufficient statistic $T(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$. This can be computed in vectorised form as follows:

\begin{align*}
\nabla_{\Theta} \log Z(\mathbf{x}, \Theta) &= \mathbb{E}_{p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}; \Theta)} [T(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})] \\
&= \sum_{\mathbf{y}} p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}; \Theta) \sum^T_{t=1} \mathbf{f}_t \\
&= \sum^T_{t=1} \sum_{\mathbf{y}} p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x} ; \Theta) \mathbf{f}_t \\
&= \sum^T_{t=1} \underbrace{\sum_{y_t} \sum_{y_{t-1}} p(y_t, y_{t-1} | \mathbf{x} ; \Theta) \mathbf{f}_t}_{(I)} \tag{*}
\end{align*}

Where $\mathbf{f}_t \in \mathbb{R}^K$ is a *local feature vector* consisting of $K$ feature functions $f_k(y_t, y_{t-1}, \mathbf{x})$ at time $t$:

$$
\mathbf{f}_t = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(y_t, y_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t) \\
\vdots \\
f_K(y_t, y_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And where expression for the sufficient statistic $T(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \in \mathbb{R}^K$ is also referred to as the *global feature vector* of the whole sequence:

$$T(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \sum^T_{t=1} \mathbf{f}_t =
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum^T_{t=1} f_1 (y_t, y_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t) \\
\vdots \\
\sum^T_{t=1} f_K (y_t, y_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

An equivalent derivation of the $k$th component of $\nabla_{\Theta} \log Z(\mathbf{x}, \Theta)$ is implied in equation $(5.20)$ in "Section 5.2 Stochastic Gradient Methods" on page 341 of the [tutorial paper](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/csutton/publications/crftut-fnt.pdf) by Sutton and MacCallum. This specifies the derivative of the *$L_2$-regularised negative conditional log-likelihood on a single $n$th training instance* with respect to $\theta_k$ as:

> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial l_n}{\partial \theta_k} = & \space \sum^T_{t=1} f_k(y^{(n)}_t, y^{(n)}_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}^{(n)}_t) \\
> & - \sum^T_{t=1} \underbrace{\sum_{y, y'} f_k(y, y', \mathbf{x}^{(n)}_t) p(y, y' | \mathbf{x}^{(n)})}_{(II)} - \frac{\theta_k}{N \sigma^2} \tag{5.20}
> \end{align*}

Now I understand that term $(II)$ is the $k$th component of term $(I)$. An exact equivalent of term $(II)$ also appears in equation $(6)$ on page 7 of Hanna Wallach's [technical report](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1011&context=cis_reports).

And I also understand that in getting from the intractable penultimate equality to the final equality $(*)$, we run a forward-backward algorithm (sum-product message passing/belief propagation/dynamic programming) as an inference subroutine. This subroutine yields the following unary and pairwise conditional distributions (on p318 of Sutton and MccCallum):

> \begin{align*}
> p(y_t, y_{t-1} | \mathbf{x}) &= \frac{1}{Z(\mathbf{x})} \alpha_{t-1}(y_{t-1}) \Psi_t(y_t, y_{t-1}, x_t) \beta_t(y_t) \tag{4.19} \\ 
> p(y_t | \mathbf{x}) &= \frac{1}{Z(\mathbf{x})} \alpha_t(y_t) \beta_t(y_t) \tag{4.20} \\
> \end{align*}

Where the parametrisation by $\Theta$ has been suppressed in the notation. Furthermore, in "Section 4: Inference" on page 313 of Sutton and McCallum, it is stated that:

> ...estimation of the parameters typically requires that we compute the marignal distribution over subsets of labels, such as over [unary] node marginals $p(y_t | \mathbf{x})$ and [pairwise] edge marginals $p(y_t, y_{t-1} | \mathbf{x})$

**On this basis, I am unable to understand why it is the case that only the pairwise conditional distribution $p(y_t, y_{t-1} | \mathbf{x})$ appears in both term $(II)$ and term $(I)$ and why there is no mention of the unary conditional distribution $p(y_t | \mathbf{x})$. Is there something I am missing here?**

*Further context can be supplied on request.*

---

**Addressing comments.**

In response to comments by @Arya McCarthy:

> The node marginals $p(y_t∣\mathbf{x})$ show up later in that section of S&M's tutorial. Check out the part on pseudolikelihood training.

Whilst an interesting observation, the use of pseudolikelihood is for approximate inference in general CRFs, and hence not relevant for exact inference in linear-chain CRFs. It is the latter I am soliciting a response on, not the former.

And also:

> That's why they were mentioned as 'useful for training' earlier. You don't need them for exact inference, but they can help for one form of approximate inference when the graph is messier. (By the way—including the equation numbers was incredibly helpful.)

I think we agree that we can read term $(II)$ as the "expectation of the $k$th feature function $f_k(y_t, y_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t)$" and we agree that we do not sum over all possible labels in $p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x} ; \Theta)$ to compute this expectation, but rather use an inference subroutine.

After having done some further digging, I am however inclined to disagree on the point that we do not need the node marginals $p(y_t | \mathbf{x}_t)$ for exact inference. I am not absolutely certain, but here are my reasons for why I think this is not the case.

Firstly, I am not sure whether "[node marginals] are useful for training" constitutes an appropriate paraphrasing of "typically requires that we compute...such as over [unary] node marginals $p(y_t | \mathbf{x})$ and [pairwise] edge marginals $p(y_t, y_{t-1} | \mathbf{x})$" in p313 of Sutton and McCallum.

The main reason why I currently inclined to diasgree on this is because I think it's an issue with the granularity of the notation. In their respective presentations mentioned above, Wallach and Sutton and McCallum refer to generic feature functions $f_k = f_k(y_t, y_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t)$, with no distinction between say a node (state) feature of the form $f_i = f_i(y_t, \mathbf{x}_t)$, and an edge (transition) feature of the form $f_j = f_j(y_t, y_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t)$. And similarly, these generic feature functions $f_k$ are parametrised by a generic parameter $\theta_k$, whereas if we introduce a distinction we might say $\theta_i$ parametrises node features and $\theta_j$ parametrises edge features.

For concreteness, in a parts-of-speech tagging case with POS tag sequences $\mathbf{y}$ and word sequences $\mathbf{x}$, then a node feature might be

$$f_i = f_i(y_t, \mathbf{x}_t) = \mathbb{I}(y_t = m) \mathbb{I}(x_t = v)$$

which takes the value 1 when POS tag $y_t$ is $m$ and word $x_t$ is $v$. An edge feature on the other hand might be

$$f_j = f_j(y_t, y_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t) = \mathbb{I}(y_t = m) \mathbb{I}(y_{t-1} = n)$$

which takes the value when current POS tag $y_t$ is $m$ and previous POS tag $y_{t-1}$ is $n$.

In light of a distinction between a node (state) feature and edge (transition) feature, my original query becomes:

1. If term $(II)$ is computed with $f_k$ as a node feature, that is, the expectation of a node feature $f_i$, then we do not compute $\mathbb{E}_{p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}; \Theta)}[f_i]$. Surely however, we would now use the node marginal given by $(4.20)$ to compute $\mathbb{E}_{p(y_t | \mathbf{x})}[f_i]$ as a point of necessity?
2. In the case we compute term $(II)$ where $f_k$ is an edge feature, that is, the expectation of an edge feature $f_j$, then we do not compute $\mathbb{E}_{p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}; \Theta)}[f_j]$. However in this case there is no need for the node marginal, as we use the edge marginal given by $(4.19)$ to compute $\mathbb{E}_{p(y_t, y_{t-1} | \mathbf{x})}[f_j]$?

**Alternatively, wouldn't the operation $\sum_{y_t} \sum_{y_t} p(y_t, y_{t-1} | \mathbf{x})$ in term $(II)$ become $\sum_{y_t} p(y_t | \mathbf{x})$ in the case that $f_k$ is a node feature function?**

Lastly, in relation to additional digging I've done, and on why I think this is a notational issue. Here is an extract from "Section 4.3.3 Dynamic Programming for Feature Expectations" on page 51 of Hanna Wallach's [MSc thesis on CRFs](http://dirichlet.net/pdf/wallach02efficient.pdf), in which a distinction between a node feature and an edge feature is made:

> Starting with the definition of the expectation of an edge feature $f_k(\mathbf{y}_{i-1}, \mathbf{y}_i, \mathbf{x})$, we note that Equation 4.16 may be rewritten as:
> \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{E}_{p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x} ; \Theta)}[f_k] = & \space \sum_{\mathbf{x}} \tilde{p}(\mathbf{x}) \sum^{n+1}_{i=1} \sum_{y', y} f_k(\mathbf{y}_{i-1} = y', \mathbf{y}_i = y, \mathbf{x}) \\
> & \times \frac{\alpha_i (y' | \mathbf{x}) M_i (y', y | \mathbf{x}) \beta_{i+1}(y | \mathbf{x})}{Z(\mathbf{x})} \tag{4.17}
> \end{align*}
> [...]
> Similarly, Lafferty et al. [2001] state that the expectation of a vertex [i.e. node] feature $g_k(\mathbf{y}_i, \mathbf{x})$ with respect to the model distribution may be expressed as:
> \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{E}_{p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}; \Theta)}[g_k] = & \space \sum_{\mathbf{x}} \tilde{p}(\mathbf{x}) \sum^{n+1}_{i=1} \sum_y g_k(\mathbf{y}_i = y, \mathbf{x}) \\
> & \times \frac{\alpha_i(y | \mathbf{x}) \beta_i(y | \mathbf{x})}{Z(\mathbf{x})} \tag{4.22}
> \end{align*}

Where the minor notational differences lie in the specification of the edge feature as $f_k$, the node feature as $g_k$, the use of $n$ to index sequence length, and the use of $M_i$ to denote the clique potential $\Psi_t$.

Given that pairwise edge marginals $p(y_t, y_{t-1} | \mathbf{x}) = \frac{\alpha_i (y' | \mathbf{x}) M_i (y', y | \mathbf{x}) \beta_{i+1}(y | \mathbf{x})}{Z(\mathbf{x})}$ and unary node marginals $p(y_t | \mathbf{x}) = \frac{\alpha_i(y | \mathbf{x}) \beta_i(y | \mathbf{x})}{Z(\mathbf{x})}$ appear in $(4.17)$ and $(4.22)$ when computing the expectations of the node and edge features, I am unable to understand or make sense of the currently unsubstantiated assertion made in the comments to the effect of

> Node marginals $p(y_t | \mathbf{x})$ are not needed for exact inference, because node features can be absorbed into edge features.

Comment: The node marginals $p(y_t \mid \mathbf{x})$ show up later in that section of S&M's tutorial. Check out the part on pseudolikelihood training.

Comment: That's why they were mentioned as 'useful for training' earlier. You don't need them for exact inference, but they can help for one form of approximate inference when the graph is messier. (By the way—including the equation numbers was incredibly helpful.)

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thank you for taking the time to assist. Would your assessment to the effect of *"node marginals $p(y_t | \mathbf{x})$ are not needed for exact inference"* change in the case that a distinction between node features and edge features is introduced? And now that I have supplied context that Wallach and Sutton and McCallum were using generic feature functions?


(P.S. Thanks for recognising that I took the time to add in equation numbers - in my experience people in general switch off if the material necessary to understand the query is not gift-wrapped and sign-posted)

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Node features can be absorbed into edge features.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy. I am unable to see why that is the case, or indeed how that would work. Are you willing or able to illustrate this algebraically, or to supply a reference illustrating your point? If it is the case that a node feature and an edge feature is just a distinction without a difference as you state, then I am trying to understand why in other sources authors would go to the trouble of explicitly drawing this distinction  (e.g. Lafferty et al's original paper or Murphy's MLPP book).